# Is there a way to convert a weight file trained in keras in h5 file to a readable format like JSON?

Tags: json, deep-learning, hdf5, h5py, fixed-point

I'm trying to run my deep learning network on a fixed point hardware. All I currently have is trained h5 model file. 
How Can I convert this h5 file to a readable format like JSON(Or any other readable format)
Also how can I convert the converted weights to fixed point format so that I can run the network on my hardware.

Comment: No need to convert. `HDF5` is a readable format (just not ASCII text). Download **HDFView** from **HDF Group**. You can open the file and view the structure and contents. Use `h5py` or `pytables` module to read the data into `numpy arrays`.

Comment: Question needs to be revised to add - the purpose of converting to a readable format, and does your inference framework support fixed point models ?

Comment: @Prabindh thank you for your comments. Readable format because I am trying to implement this inference network in c/c++ and yes the inference framework supports only fixed point models

Comment: @kcw78 thank you for your comments. Yes that is the last option I have, to read the data into numpy arrays and individually convert them to Fixed point format. Was looking for an easier method if available.